# Running AT90USB646/Atmega32u4 between 3.3V and 5V

Tags: microcontroller, power, atmega

I'm working on a battery powered project that will need the AT90USB646 µC. From the data sheet, I know it can take from 2.7V to 5.5V at 8MHz. However, apparently, lower voltages reduce power consumption tremendously.

I can't run it at 3.3V since I have LED's with a 4.2 V_f and I'd rather not do 2 separate power rails if I can avoid it. I'm hoping to supply it with a boost-converter output of 4.5-4.6V. The remainder of my circuit is simply some LED's, some switches, and a bluetooth chip fed regulated 3.3V.

Would there be any issues running the µC somewhere between 3.3V and 5V standards?

Comment: No, it should work fine, but if you already have 3.3V devices, why not run everything at 3.3V except the LEDs, and run only the LEDs with a small charge pump? That solves the problem of having different IO voltages between devices and the need for level conversion between them.

Comment: @Justme I definitely considered that too, but I actually have an array of 80 LED's or so, drawing near 400mA, so I figured that a charge pump wouldn't be able to handle that. I know I could do 2 in parallel, but BOM costs and board spacing aren't in its favor.

Comment: @felix-jen, what about a low-side switch for the LEDs? The µC could run off the 3.3 V regulator with the Bluetooth chip, and the LEDs could run off the battery with current limiting resistors. Something like this [low-side switch example](http://tinyurl.com/yxlc6njv)

Comment: Hi Felix. I managed to run at90usb646 at 16Mhz 5V, (typical bus power 5V mode according to the datasheet). I want to integrate a bluetooth LE module later, so self power 3V (with a Li-Po battery) should be my goal. But I fail to run it at 8Mhz 3.3V (adding a 5 to 3.3 LDO, either bus power of self power). The MCU can be programmed via ISP, but could not be recognized as a USB device on my laptop, neither application or bootloader. Could you help a hand https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/590388/297671, or kindly share your schematic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since  power  increases with Vcc(I = V^2f; where `I` is current and `f` is frequency), you can reduce power consumption without limiting the maximum operating frequency by minimizing  the voltage of the device.
For example, running at 4.5V instead of 5.0V for a 16MHz device, drops power by almost 20% without compromising the device’s performance. As evidenced by the power  equation, reducing clock frequency also plays an important role in power savings. If you can optimize your code to run at 10MHz instead of 16MHz, current consumption is reduced by 30%-40%.
[See Info here](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/29877/battery.pdf)