# How to make AT90USB646 run at 3.3v VCC?

Tags: avr, ldo, teensy

**[WHAT I DID]** I've made one prototype of AT90USB646 running at 16MHz, 5V. The design is almost the same as Teensy++ (schematics can be found here https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic.html).

**[WHAT I AM DOING]** Later I made another prototype adopting the Teensy++ 2.0 design. Two slight differences which I guess are not the cause of problem:

1. MCU: AT90USB646 instead of AT90USB1286
2. LDO: SPX3819 instead of MCP1825 (3.3v output)

When LDO is bypassed (shorts VIN and VOUT), the board is running at 5V, either 8MHz or 16MHz oscillator works fine.

**[MY PROBLEM]** When LDO is working, the voltage measured from MCU is 3.3V, but the device could not be recognized by host (my laptop), both 8Mhz and 16Mhz oscillators don't work. MCU flashed Atmel official bootloader (bootloader_at90usb64_1.0.0.hex), fuse settings are:

- L:  0xDE
- H: 0x9B
- E: 0xF3

**[MY QUESTION]** What would be the root cause and how could I fix?

Comment: 8MHz only needs 2.7V so it could be layout with noise.

Comment: It would help if you posted the schematics. And PCB layout. The schematics you link to are for a different MCU brand and model, so while you think it is almost same, it is completely different. Also the AVR is not rated to work at 16 MHz on a 3.3V supply voltage, so don't do that.

Comment: @Justme scroll down to the bottom of the page, there are schematics for Teensy++ 1.0 and  Teensy++ 2.0, which use AT90USB646 and AT90USB1286 respectively. Also a Teensy++ 2.0 PCB layout that I follow a lot.

Answer (score 1):

AT90USB646 requires at least 4.5V for 16 MHz stable operation.

[image: Scheme from datasheet]

This MCU includes internal voltage regulator for supplying USB data voltage. If you have external 3.3V regulator I think this needs to be disable for USB operation:

• 0 – UVREGE: USB pad regulator Enable
Set to enable the USB pad regulator. Clear to disable the USB pad regulator

Also, make sure you've read & understand USB part of the datasheet. There are some things to know how to power & connect your MCU depending on the application (i.e. self-powered or bus-powered at least).

PS: Shorting LDO output with input isn't a good idea, this can burn it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the slight difference between several modes in 22.3.1. My plan is to add bluetooth support with 3.7v Li-Po battery. Also a Li-Po charger (might be MCP73831T-2ACI/OT, which I found used on a 32U4 board) powered by USB. So I guess Figure 22-6 would be the best fit for me, right?

Comment: LiPo batteries runs up to 4.2V fully charged and down to 2.7V. Figure 22-6 shows self-powered device with 3.0-3.6V I/O. If you add external 3.3V LDO such as SPX3819 which also has 340mV dropout voltage, that way you'll can only go to ~3.64V on battery, i.e. without full range. Besides it will vary based on load. But rest is much out of scope of this question.